# Firebase Storage Reference Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, image, reference, storage

I want to display images on my homepage using Firebase Storage and Javascript.
I can read all references of the Images in a folder, but how can I display it on my homepage?

```js
// Now we get the references of these images
listAll(listRef).then((res) => {
    res.items.forEach(function (imageRef) {
        // And finally display them
        console.log(imageRef);
        displayImage(imageRef);
    });
}).catch((error) => {
    // Handle any errors
    console.log("Error 1");
});

function displayImage(imageRef) {
    test = imageRef.getDownloadURL();
    imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
        // TODO: Display the image on the UI
        const img = document.getElementById('tierFoto');
        img.setAttribute('src', url);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // Handle any errors
        console.log("Error 2");
    });
}}
```

I always get Error 1
The reference (imageRef) looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQC1W.png)

Comment: What output you are getting as output of this - `imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {`

Comment: There is no output, it jumpes to "Error1"

Comment: what error do you get in that block? Tried console error?

Comment: TypeError: imageRef.getDownloadURL is not a function\n    at displayImage (http://localh

message:'imageRef.getDownloadURL is not a function'
stack:'TypeError: imageRef.getDownloadURL is not a function\n    at dis

Comment: Tried `imageRef.fullPath()` ?

Comment: also Error "TypeError: imageRef.fullPath is not a function\n"

Comment: Have you changed all occurences of `getDownloadURL()` with `fullPath()` ?

Comment: Yes, I changed all.